# JavaScript && opertor in return statement

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of JavaScript code as follows:

```
function main(condition){
    if(condition){
        doSomething();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

now I want to refactor this code to get rid of the "if" statement. Here is what I want to do

```
function main(condition){
    var doSomethingAndReturnObj = function(){
        doSomething();
        return obj;
    }
    return condition && doSomethingAndReturnObj();
}
```

here is where I need help. The caller of main function expects a return value of "undefined" or an obj. In my refactored code, would my

**return condition && doSomethingAndReturnObj();**

convert the return value to a true and false type?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Why not "return (condition ? doSomethingAndReturnObj() : undefined);" ?

Comment: You neglected to specify if `condition` will always contain either `undefined` or a truthy value. That's kind of important.

Comment: well, I want my code to be "elegant", I know it's a totally geek thing. But if the code does what I expect, it's more compact and, in my opinion, easier to read.

Comment: selbie's suggestion is probably the cleanest way to return either an object or undefined, but regarding your last question on "convert[ing] the return value to a true and false type" the way this is done in JavaScript is to use "!!".  That is for any expression e, the expression !!e produces true when e is truthy and false otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's `&&` operator is **coalescing**.

```
js> 0 && 7
0
js> 1 && 7
7
```

Comment: Thanks! even though I had to google for what coalescing means :)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: no, `&&` does not convert things to Boolean values.

`&&` only continues if it gets a ***truthy*** value, returning the first ***falsy*** value, or the last value, meaning:

```
undefined && true == undefined
true && true      == true
true && false     == false
1 && 2 && 3       == 3
1 && 2 && 0 && 4  == 0
```

So if your condition is falsy, e.g. `false` or `undefined`, it will return that exact value.  If your condition is truthy, it will return whatever `doSomethingAndReturnObj()` returns.

falsy values for reference: `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false`, `NaN`, `""`.  ***everything*** else is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by doSomethingAndReturnObj() will not be converted to true or false.

Comment: This helped to solve my puzzle, but Ignacio was a bit faster to answer, so I will mark his as answer.